# how to find the corresponding point in other row of an array in matlab?

Tags: matlab

i have an array lets say

x =

```
 1     2     2
 5     8     7
```

now i want to get the corresponding values of a number in 2nd row.
like i have
 number =2

and i want

ans= 8 and 7

as 8 and 7 are the corresponding points for 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
X(2,X(1,:)==2)
```

should do.  Hope you can figure out how.