# Matlab - selecting values

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a matrix

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5 ; 1,1,1, 21, 43]
```

I want to select the entries from the first row that have a 1 in the row below them, basically end up with `[1,2,3]` as a result. How do I do this? Thank you very much

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to find the corresponding point in other row of an array in matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862530/how-to-find-the-corresponding-point-in-other-row-of-an-array-in-matlab)

Answer (score 2):

You can use logical indexing like this:

```
result = A(1, A(2,:) == 1)
```

This says take the first row of `A` and columns for which the expression `A(2,:) == 1` holds true.

`A(2,:) == 1` checks for every column in row 2 whether the value is 1 and returns an array of true or false that acts as a selector as described above. In your example, it would produce an array `[1 1 1 0 0]`.

Comment: how about the same problem for the transposed version of the matrix?

Comment: @Viktor: you can do the same thing with the transposition, just swap what your indexing -- rows vs. columns.